# c++ Automatically print function return value

Tags: c++, scope, macros

I'm debugging some c++ code mostly with logs and was wondering if there's a way to have each function print its return value.

I know I can store it in a variable at the calling function's scope and use that to print, but this requires adding lines of code, temp variables, and well - more work on my side.

So I was thinking of adding a MACRO at the beginning of every function I want and that macro would print the name of the function at the start of the block and at the end of it with its return value.

I already have a macro for printing the function at the start\end of the block using something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define SCOPE_LOG()  ScopedLog log(__FUNCTION__)

class ScopedLog {
public:
    ScopedLog(std::string msg) : _msg(msg) {
        std::cout << "Entering: " << _msg << std::endl;
    }
    ~ScopedLog() {
        std::cout << "Exiting: " << _msg << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::string _msg;
};

int foo(int x)
{
    SCOPE_LOG();
    return x + 1;
}

int main()
{
    foo(5);
    return 0;
}
```

The above will print:

```
Entering: foo
Exiting: foo
```

I want to be able to have it print:

```
Entering: foo
Exiting: foo , retVal = 6
```

I had a few ideas of how to do something that does this but they weren't ideal (to say the least).

So, is there a way to do such a thing? (maybe by accessing the stack at the scopedLog d'tor?)

I'd appreciate any answer even it it makes some assumptions, is incomplete etc.

I'm more interested in new ways I could not think of that do something rather than the perfect-yet-never-use-this solution.

Comment: can you change the call from `foo(5)` to something like `LOG_MACRO(foo(5))`?

Comment: Without hacking the stack, there's no way of knowing the return value from the `ScopedLog` destructor. You have to think of other solutions/designs.

Comment: @m.s. I'd rather not. I want something I can copy-paste to a function and have it work, maybe with just mild changes. Wrapping the function call could become a pain

Comment: Just learn to use the debugger. Any extra code you need to delete at a later stage

Comment: @Ed Heal , when I release my code to clients and they get a bug, they can't use a debugger. I can use logs though. And rest assure the code will not always print the loggings

Comment: They send you a report of the fault. You reproduce it with the debugger. The alternative is to log everything. Then make it very slow and use disk space. This assumes the  logging system does not have any bugs

Comment: Or, they reproduce it after enabling the logging thus making only that run slow. Please stop with these condescending remarks